# Why am I getting an error here? React Todo list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a todo list using React but i cant seem to understand why I am getting the error: "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state."

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class Todo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      list: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this)
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this)
    this.add = this.add.bind(this)
  }
  add(){ //Adds a new task
    
    const newItem = {
      value: this.state.input,
      id: Math.random + Math.random
    };
    const listed = [...this.state.list]
    listed.push(newItem)
    this.setState({
      input: '',
      list: listed
    })
  }
  removeItem(id){ //deletes a task
    const list = [...this.state.list]
    const updatedList = list.filter(obj => {
      return obj.id !== id
    })
    this.setState({
      list: updatedList
    })
  }
  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }
  reset(e){
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <form action="" onSubmit={this.reset}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.input} placeholder='Enter a task..' onChange={this.handleChange}  />
          <button onClick={this.add}>Add Task</button>
        {this.state.list.map(item => {   //updates when a task is added or removed
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
            <h1>{item.value}</h1>
            <button onClick={this.removeItem(item.id)}>X</button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders

Comment: Thanks I am learning React and didn't know this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling removeItem on render. It needs to be wrapped in a separate function:

```
 <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(item.id)}>X</button>
```

So that you only call it onClick and not on render.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to improve the id system I have in place, I encounter dupes often

Comment: You mean that you get the same ids multiple times?

Comment: Yes, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

1. `<button onClick={this.removeItem(item.id)}>X</button>`
   In this button the event handler you have provided runs immediately due to the presents of the `()` at the end. To prevent this and still provide your argument `item.id` you can enclose the handler `this.removeItem(item.id)` with in another function.
   I like the arrow function for this so mine looks like this
   `<button onClick={ ()=>this.removeItem(item.id) }>X</button>`.
2. `Math.random + Math.random` is not returning a number like you would want for the element key. This is because your have neglected to include `()` at telling JS to run the function and return an int.

After making these changes, I ran it in codepen.io and it seemed to work fine.